# How to add Alphabetical numeration? Test provided

Tags: java

Update: I solved it on my own. Will try to share solution later. Thanks.

**Need to order a series of characters using an alphabetical list.** [See test below, it is quite self-explanatory] I have problems with it because I don't know where to add the loop (I tried different options but could not find the right one).

I'm trying to add an alphabetic list, like the following one. But replacing the numbers for letters.

Name:

1. | Something
2. | Something
3. | Something

**TEST**:

```
expected: <1234
a|v·~·
b|╔╗═┃
c|╚·╚╗
d|·M·^> 

but was: <1234
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz|v·~·
|╔╗═┃
|╚·╚╗
|·M·^>
```

Code:

```
    public String toString() {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            response.append("" + i);
        }
        response.append("\n");

        for(char alphabet = 'a'; alphabet <= 'z'; alphabet++){
            response.append(alphabet);
        }

        for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
            response.append("|");
            for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                response.append(board[i][j].getType().getUnicodeRepresentation());
            }
            response.append("\n");
        }
        return response.toString();
    }
```

**Adding another try:**
**TEST**

```
expected: <1234
a|v·~·
b|╔╗═┃
c|╚·╚╗
d|·M·^>

but was: <1234
a|v·~·╔╗═┃╚·╚╗·M·^
b|v·~·╔╗═┃╚·╚╗·M·^
c|v·~·╔╗═┃╚·╚╗·M·^
d|v·~·╔╗═┃╚·╚╗·M·^>
```

Code:

```
public String toString() {
        StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

        for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
            response.append("" + i);
        }
        response.append("\n");

        for(char alphabet = 'a'; alphabet <= 'd'; alphabet++){
            response.append(alphabet);
            response.append("|");
            for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
                for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
                    response.append(board[i][j].getType().getUnicodeRepresentation());
                }
            }
            response.append("\n");
        }

        return response.toString();
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, but I do not find your input "self explanatory". Please remember: you are asking other people to spend their time to help you with your problem. So you want to make that as easy and fast for us as possible. And that starts with a *clear* problem description, and just the right amount of code. So, please see [mcve] and then enhance your question accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understood what you're trying to do, but you can try:

```
for(int i =0, char alphabet = 'a'; alphabet <= 'z'; alphabet++, i++){
    response.append(alphabet);
    response.append("|");
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
        response.append(board[i][j].getType().getUnicodeRepresentation());
    }
    response.append("\n");
}
```

There might be problems with the indexing(specifically `i`) because you didn't provide any info about `board` or `size` or your intention in general. `i` will probabily be out of bounds, because something doesn't make sense. From your example it looks like `size` is 4, but your first loop runs all the way from `a` to `z`, so for `e`, which cells from `board` should you concat to the string?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to index the alphabet and then assign each series of characters to the corresponding index.
The new code would be:

```
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

    for(int i = 1; i <= size; i++) {
        response.append("" + i);
    }
    response.append("\n");

    String[] lines = new String[size];

    for(int i = 0, char alphabet = 'a'; alphabet <= 'z' && i < size; alphabet++, i++){
        lines[i] = alphabet + "";
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        lines[i] += ("|");
        for (int j = 0; j < size; j++){
            lines[i] += board[i][j].getType().getUnicodeRepresentation();
        }
    }
    
    for(int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        response.append(lines[i]);
        response.append("\n");
    }
    
    return response.toString();
}
```

Comment: Where is `j` defined?